# Using AWS ECR with portainer push/pull images not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-registry, amazon-ecr, portainer

I'm having trouble getting portainer to work properly with AWS ECR.
I got my images up and running on ECR, if I run my docker-compose with the command line via SSH it's working as expected. If i do a simple docker pull `{myid}.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/{repository}` it's working also.

But if i try to go to the same image via the portainer GUI and hit pull/push i always got this message:

[image]

My repository settings:
[image]
At least with portainer i can have a good overview of my running container and available images, but it's a shame that, so far, i can't update them with the GUI. Usually when making an update, i push (from my local computer) and then in portainer i re-create the container and specify to pull the new image. Of course, as of now, i can't with the failing pull..

When using docker "cli" i can do whatever i want, push, pull and my docker-compose which is using my ECR images can run without issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find a solution yet? I'm having the same problem..

Comment: Unfortunatly nope, i'm using aws cli to do that with my npm tasks. If interested i added the solution in my post.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by creating a cronjob on the server that runs the login script for the AWS ECR Repository (explained [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/getting-started-cli.html)) every 30 minutes or so. This way you don't need to add the registry in portainer.

You could retrieve the password throgh AWS CLI explained [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/get-login-password.html) and use this to login with portainer.
But the reason this is a **bad idea** is because AWS resets the password twice a day so the login would only be valid for 12 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatly nope, i'm using aws cli to do that with my npm tasks. If interested here it is:
`

```
  "publish": "npm run _docker:build && npm run _aws:auth && npm run _aws:tag && npm run _aws:push && npm run _docker:prune",
  "_docker:build": "docker build -t *yourImageName* .",
  "_aws:auth": "aws ecr get-login-password --region eu-west-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin *yourID*.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com",
  "_aws:tag": "docker tag *yourImageName:latest* yourID.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/*yourImageName*:latest",
  "_aws:push": "docker push *yourID*.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/*yourImageNam*e:latest",
  "_docker:prune": "docker image prune -f"
```

`

Answer (score 0):

after signifact amount of time, seems I solved this one.
The issue was in internal portainer overlay network conflicting with subnetwork on EC2 instances.
So, internal docker DNS was overlayed by Subnet CIDR.
I had CIDR 10.0.1.0/24 on AWS and seems like docker also uses it.
After recreating subnet with the new CIDR like 192.168.1.0/20 everything works!